# Creating a select all text button in angularJS

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, forms

I've searched around for answers, but haven't found anything directly specific to this.

Inside a model, I have a disabled/read-only text-area, and a button to select all the text inside it (Which the user can then copy - if anyone knows how to make a copy function along with the select button, that would be neat).

However, when the button is clicked, while it looks like it's selecting all the text-area text, it's only selecting the text-area element. When you go to  copy and paste text, nothing is available in the clipboard.

Here's the relevant code:

```
$scope.selectAll = function() {
  var selection = $window.getSelection();
  var range = document.createRange();
  var text = angular.element('textarea');
  range.selectNodeContents(text[0]);
  selection.removeAllRanges();
  selection.addRange(range);
};
```

In the HTML:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button class="btn btn-default" data-ng-click="selectAll()">Select All</button>
<button class="btn btn-warning" data-ng-click="close()">Close</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a directive and use `textarea.select()` method

Something like this

```
angular.module('myApp.directives', []).
  directive('selectAll', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {},
      link: function (scope,elem,attr) {
        var textarea = elem.parent().find("textarea")[0];
        elem.bind('click', function() {
          textarea.select();
        });
      }
    }
});
```

This assumes that the button and textarea elements share the same parent.

Working plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/MOHaiDU0zAqwgJEgIo1j?p=preview

Comment: Thank you. I tried that, but got a " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'select' of undefined" in the console.

Comment: should be parent().children().find() I updated my answer

Comment: I found it was the [0] after textarea that was throwing the error. Not sure what to make of that.

Comment: glad you got it working, I admit I didn't test the code but if removing the [0] works then perfect.  Please accept the answer if it answered your question.

Comment: It doesn't select anything at all, but it doesn't throw any errors. I'll try something else. Thank you!

Comment: my original code works correctly and I've added a working plunk to demonstrate

Comment: Works great. I just had to change the textarea value to angular.element('textarea')[0];